# Does there exist a closed-form expression for the following function?

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, closed-form

I would like to find a closed-form expression for the function that is defined as follows:

$T_{s}(x) = x^{s}(1 - x^{s}), \text{for prime } x \\
T_{s}(x) = x^{s}, \text{otherwise}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to asking for an indicator function for the primes: Given $T_s(x)$,

$$
\frac{T_s(x)-x^s}{x^s(1-x^s)-x^s}=x^{-s}-x^{-2s}T_s(x)
$$

is an indicator function for the primes, and conversely given an indicator function $I(x)$ of the primes,

$$
T_s(x)=x^s(1-I(x)x^s)
$$

is your function. Various indicator functions for the primes are known, e.g. [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08670).